# No need to create an index on a column with a UNIQUE constraint, right?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I have a table with three columns.

```
_id (primary key)    word (unique)     frequency
```

In [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/README.md) I create the table like this

```swift
try db.run( userDictionary.create(ifNotExists: true) {t in
    t.column(wordId, primaryKey: true)
    t.column(word, unique: true)
    t.column(frequency, defaultValue: 1)
    })
```

I believe the SQLite syntax that would be

```sql
CREATE TABLE "words" (
    "_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "word" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    "frequency" INTEGER DEFAULT 1
)
```

I was preparing to add an index on the "word" column to speed up performance since I will have to do frequent queries on it. But then I read the following interesting statement in the [Indexes tutorial by TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm):

> Implicit Indexes:
>
> Implicit indexes are indexes that are automatically created by the
>   database server when an object is created. **Indexes are automatically
>   created for primary key constraints and unique constraints.**

So since I already added a unique constraint to the "word" column, there is no need to do anything else. Is that correct? I tried to confirm this in the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) but I couldn't find it.

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master): "UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints on tables cause SQLite to create internal indexes".

Comment: @CL. "*internal indexes*" is why `PRIMARY KEY` and `CREATE INDEX` show up as `index` -type entries in `sqlite_master`, while `UNIQUE` -constraints do not?

Comment: @user4157124 Indexes created for UNIQUE constraints show up in `sqlite_master`, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct. UNIQUE creates an index. This is how most databases actually enforce it.

Imagine they didn't create an index, what would happen. They would literally need to do a full table scan on every insert and that means performance would go out the window.